# Duration for Sound on the 8051

Tags: c, frequency, 8051

I am trying to create a short tune using timers on the 8051. I am trying to send a square wave with a specified frequency to create the notes.
However, with my current code all I am getting is one infinite note, that never stops playing. Any help figuring out how to stop the note, and create a duration function would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include<reg932.h>
sbit speaker=P1^7;
void tone(unsigned char, unsigned char);
void main()
{
    P1M1 = 0;
    P1M2 = 0;
    tone(0xC8, 0xF3);
}

void tone(unsigned char highval, unsigned char lowval)
{
   TMOD=0x01;
   TL0=lowval;
   TH0=highval;
   TR0=1;
   while(TF0==0);
   speaker=0;
   TR0=0;
   TF0=0;
}
```

Comment: how many Hz frequency you are trying to generate and what is P1M1 and P1M2 ? May I know that ?

Comment: In main loop try while(1){  speaker = ~speaker; tone(0xC8, 0xF3); } remove other stuff from main

Comment: Why does the `main()` not contain a `while(1)` loop (infinite loop)?? what do you think happens when the execution reaches end of main?? Dont you think that `tone()` would be executed only once and to generate correct tone, you will require to turn-On and Off, the buzzer/speaker??
why write a polling software routine for timer interrupt and prefer not writing an interrupt sub routine???
_in pursuit to find answers to above questions, you'll end up as a better programmer of 8051_

Answer (score 0):

I haven't programmed 8051's devices in a long time, but here's what I'd do:

1.a. figure out if it's tone() that never exits

1.b. if it is, I'd make sure that the while loop is indeed in there (see the disassembly of tone()), if it's not, the compiler optimizes the check out and it needs fixing (e.g. declaring TF0 as volatile)

1.c. see if the check is correct (the right bit in the right register, etc)

2. write an assembly routine to waste N CPU clocks, use the slowest instruction (was MUL or DIV the slowest?) in a loop or simply repeated M times so you get like a 10 ms delay or something, write a C function to call that routine as many times as necessary (e.g. 100 times for 1 second). (You could use a timer here, but this may be the simplest)